# ffmpeg Windows stream to Twitch with video from pipe only sends ~100 frames and get stuck

Tags: python-3.x, windows, ffmpeg, subprocess

I try to stream rawVideo (a numpy array) to Twitch using Python with ffmpeg on Windows. But after ~100 frames i just get stuck.

My SubProcess Parameter:

```py
command = [
    "ffmpeg.exe",
        '-f', 'rawvideo',
        '-vcodec','rawvideo',
        '-s', '480x640', 
        '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24',
        '-r', '30',
        '-i', '-', 
        '-vcodec', 'libx264',
        '-b:v' , '5M',
        '-acodec', 'aac',
        '-b:a', '256k',
        '-r','30',
        '-f', 'flv', 'rtmp://live-fra.twitch.tv/app/%removed for stackoverflow%'
]
[...]
pipe = subprocess.Popen( command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Sending Frames:

```py
frames = 0
frame = np.zeros((480, 640, 3))
#print(pipe,dir(pipe))
while 1:
    try:
        pipe.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())   # < gets stuck here after ~100 frames     
        frames += 1
        print("frame_send", frames)       
    except Exception as e:
         out, ffmpeg_error = pipe.communicate()
         print("error:" , ffmpeg_error  , e , out )
         break
    time.sleep( 1 / 30 )
```

There were no errors it just stuck on "pipe.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())"

Comment: Does it still happen if you save to disk?

Comment: I fixed it for everyone who might encounter the same problem just set stderr to none 
subprocess.Popen( command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None)

Comment: @K0IN You can make an answer to the question since you found a solution.